# Unable to open VLP-16 Webserver & Cannot get Scan Data in rviz

Tags: ros, vlp-16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 (NOT a virtual machine), and I am having trouble connection with my VLP-16.

In Wireshark, I can see that data is being sent along eth0 (ethernet 0). I have configured the ethernet port to the following:

`Address - 192.168.1.55   Netmask - 255.255.255.0   Gateway - 0.0.0.0`
`

When I open a terminal I type:

`sudo ifconfig eth0 10.66.171.45`

because the IP address the VLP-16 is sending fron is 10.66.171.45 (as seen in Wireshark)

Afterward in the terminal I write:

`sudo route add 192.168.1.1 eth0`

as stated in the VLP velodyne manual, online. So, in Wireshark I'm able to see that packets are coming, however in rviz I'm unable to see them and I'm also not able to open the webserver for my VLP-16. Thus, I assume I am having some sort of configuration problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248868/unable-to-open-vlp-16-webserver-&-cannot-get-scan-data-in-rviz/) by [ryan4588](https://answers.ros.org/users/28629/ryan4588/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Easiest would be to configure either:

1. your VLP to have an IP in the `192.168.1.0` range (so it's in the same network as your PC), or
2. give `eth0` an IP in the `10.0.0.0` range (as that's what your VLP is in)

All other options will need careful configuration of your network stack.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1